# three.js stops working, when I move my three.js-referring html-file

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is weird..

I downloaded three.js in my directory 'brick':

> git clone https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git

this makes a subdir:

```
brick/three.js/
```

When I go to

```
brick/three.js/examples
```

and in Firefox open the file

```
brick/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html
```

a nice rotating cube shows up. Then when I copy it (that is, brick/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html) to the directory 'brick' and change the three.min.js reference in the new brick/webgl_geometry_cube.html accordingly, brick/webgl_geometry_cube.html doesn't work - no cube shows up when I open it in firefox.

Let me be more specific about the three.min.js reference in webgl_geometry_cube.html. The top of
    brick/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html
looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - geometry - cube</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                background-color: #000000;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var mesh;
```

when I copy it to

```
brick/webgl_geometry_cube.html
```

I change the line

```
<script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="three.js/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

I verify that this new reference actually works, by opening

```
brick/webgl_geometry_cube.html
```

in firefox, choosing 'view source', and in the source follow the reference to three.min.js. If I am shown the source code of three.min.js (which I am), Im happy.

But why then, does no cube rotate when opening the moved file in Firefox? I'm puzzled. There doesn't seem to be any other path-dependent references in webgl_geometry_cube.html. The full source code of webgl_geometry_cube.html can be seen here:

[webgl_geometry_cube.html on Github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html)

Also, how do I go about debugging this? Can I do some sort of step-through of the code, to see where the two files diverge in their execution?

Comment: Did you adjust the `textures/crate.gif` in the JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example uses a texture, so you need to adjust the path `textures/crate.gif` in the JavaScript too, otherwise the texture isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was another reference in webgl_geometry_cube.html that I hadn't spotted: The file crate.gif is referred to in line 34, and this reference shall of course also be updated to reflect the new relative position of crate.gif:

```
three.js/examples/textures/crate.gif
```

This solution was given by user [maenu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656878/maenu). Thank you man..